# Embedding .net remoting program in WEB

Tags: c#, remoting

So, here is a deal.
I have client-server application(dotNet remoting). Client side has few trackbars, checkboxes, buttons and picturebox. Server is a console application and does only calculation from client. Client's picturebox make some visualisation of calculation in picturebox. All calulations and relative classes are in dll file.

Now I have to embed client application in web site. All kind of technologies are accepted, but I want to minimize forces applied to embedding. So, what is the best way to do embedding?

Comment: your question makes no sense. Pleas eclarify wehat you are trying to do...

Comment: my task makes no sense=(
i need to embed c# application in web site. I can make java applet, but I have to rewrite a lot of code. Thats why i'm looking for alternative ways

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Mmmm, eclairs...

Comment: @aehiilrs: lol!  ...and I can longer edit it...

Answer (score 0):

What about [SilverLight](http://silverlight.net) or [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash)?

Comment: i've alreade thought about flash. it also requires code rewriting.

and what about silverlight, do I need to rewrite code in some way?

Comment: @flufferok: I would expect so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web site that accesses your remoting server and renders output as HTML.  I seriously doubt that you will be able to get remoting working inside a browser environment, even using something like Silverlight.

If you don't want to use a full blown web server then use the .net class HttpListener in your server application to create an embedded web server.

Comment: the main problem is embedding c# controls in web. i can use another server to parse the requests. i just need the easiest way(no code rewriting, or just minimizing it).

Comment: I presume you mean Winforms controls.  To my knowledge there is no way of displaying winforms controls in a browser.  If your UI was based on WPF you would have more options but with Winforms you are screwed.  You really need to ask whoever is setting this requirement, why they want it in a browser.  That will help you get to a solution.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's just a task in my university. looks like i hava to rewrite all code to make an Japplet

Comment: Nooooooooo!!!!  Anything but! :-)   Seriously though, nobody uses Java Applets to deliver content in the web browser.  Try Javascript, or Silverlight or even flash, but not Java Applets.  Deploy your app as ClickOnce application and it will deploy from the web just as easy as a web application.

Comment: are you sure that silverlight can work with some kind of server application?

Comment: Absolutely.  HttpWebRequest is your friend. http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a C# application and access it through a web server, look into iHttpHandler. You need to compile to a DLL, and configure your IIS server.

There are a number of tutorials on the web. One is: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomImageHandler.aspx